# How to do expression replacement in sage as in Mathematica?

Tags: python, wolfram-mathematica, sage

In Mathematica, I can do expression replacement like x^2 -> x which changes power 2 of x into x. I wonder if there are any similar functionalities in sage?

```
R = PolynomialRing(ZZ, 2, "a")
a = R.gens()
(a[0] + a[1])^2
Out[173]:
a0^2 + 2*a0*a1 + a1^2
```

I would like to change all powers of a (> 1) into power 1. So replace a^k -> a for k >= 1.

So the desire output would be a0 + 2*a0*a1 + a1

Answer (score 0):

I am now using string replacement to achieve the result. Let me know if you have a better method. Thanks!

```
def ReplaceExpression(p, locals):
    s = str(p)
    s1 = re.sub(r'\b(a\d+)\^\d+', "\g<1>", s)
    return sage_eval(s1, locals = locals)

adict = dict([(str(i), i) for i in a])
ReplaceExpression((a[0] + a[1])^2, adict)

Out[1]: 2*a0*a1 + a0 + a1
```

Comment: You could ask this in https://ask.sagemath.org/questions, I hope this type of question has a simpler answer. Trying to replace Mathematica with sagemath is really difficult for people that want to manipulate expressions like this.

Comment: Have you tried to use wildcards? Type SR.wild? to get help on this.

Answer (score 0):

SageMath uses SymPy for symbolic math, so there should be a `replace()` method on your expression.

```
>>> A
a0**2 + 2*a0*a1 + a1**2
>>> A.replace(lambda expr: isinstance(expr, sympy.Pow), lambda expr: expr.args[0])
2*a0*a1 + a0 + a1
```

This uses the variation with two functions as arguments.  The first is a filter which tests for nodes in the expression tree to be substituted and the second calculates the replacement.

We are searching for any `Pow` node and replace it by it's first argument.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a quotient of your polynomial ring by an ideal.

```
sage: R = PolynomialRing(ZZ, 2, "a")
sage: a = R.gens()
sage: b = (a[0] + a[1])^2
sage: b
a0^2 + 2*a0*a1 + a1^2
sage: J = R.ideal([x^2 - x for x in a])
sage: J
Ideal (a0^2 - a0, a1^2 - a1) of Multivariate Polynomial Ring in a0, a1 over Integer Ring
sage: S = R.quo(J)
sage: S
Quotient of Multivariate Polynomial Ring in a0, a1 over Integer Ring by the ideal (a0^2 - a0, a1^2 - a1)
sage: S(b)
2*a0bar*a1bar + a0bar + a1bar
```